# Dart transformer for packages

Tags: dart, transformer-model

I am trying to make a dart transformer that also runs on packages, but I cant figure out how I currently have the following

```dart
class MyTransformer extends Transformer implements LazyTransformer {
  MyTransformer.asPlugin();

  String get allowedExtensions => ".dart";

  void declareOutputs(DeclaringTransform transform) {
    // Just transforms a Dart file in place.
    transform.declareOutput(transform.primaryId);
  }

  Future apply(Transform transform) {
    //Only prints files that are in project how to include packages?
    print(transform.primaryInput.id.path);
    return //do work here
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance I have know idea how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not yet supported. See http://dartbug.com/18489 for more details (and http://dartbug.com/20267

Comment: If all packages you want to apply the transformer are yours you just need to add the dependency and transformer config in each package. As far as I know transformers in dependencies are applied as well. Othereise I think you are out of luck.